# Will compass generate the images for us?

Tags: compass-sass

"generatedImagesDir" parameter works well with below codes, does it mean that this only work with compass sprites utils?

```
@import "compass/utilities/sprites";
@import "icons/*.png";
@include all-icons-sprites;
```

**Previous questions:**

Compass success to compile the css to folder ".tmp/styles", I use the new one in index.html as below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../.tmp/styles/style.css">
```

but there is no "../img/1-1.png" image in "../.tmp" folder, 
so how can I let compass to create a new "1-1.png" in to generatedImagesDir? Is "generatedImagesDir" paramenter used to do such a thing? Thanks.

**Grunt task**

```
compass: {
  options: {
      importPath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components',
      sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
      cssDir: '.tmp/styles',

      imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/img',
      generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/img',

      javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
      fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
      httpImagesPath: '/img',
      httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/img/generated',
      httpFontsPath: '/styles/fonts',
      relativeAssets: false

  },
  dist: {},
  server: {
    options: {
      debugInfo: true
    }
  }
},
```

**CSS**

```
.ap-navbar-bg.navbar-inner {
   background-color: #E86224;
   background-image: url(../img/1-1.png);
   height: 40px;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compass will generate for you those png's you wanted as sprites, but the rest of the images includes on the sass file should not be generated by compass, they must be there already, on their own folder.

What compass does its to have a look to the images path, in your case: <%= yeoman.app %>/img, the one you specified.

Compass will help you with the routes in this case, but not generate new images.

Does this help you ?